# Construct a Reed Solomon code: find the parity check matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise, but I need a check/opinion on how to solve it.

> Construct a Reed-Solomon code with dimensions $[12,7]$ over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ and find a parity check matrix for the code $C$. Hint: $2$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{13}$.

---

First thing: I have $\delta=12-7+1=6$, so the minimum distance is exactly $6$. Also, I choose to build a narrow-sense code, so the defining set is $T = \mathcal{C}_1 \cup \ldots \cup \mathcal{C}_{5}$.

As $12=n=13-1$, then $\mathcal{C}_i=\{ i \}$, so the generator polynomial is $$g(x)=(x-2)(x-2^2)(x-2^3)(x-2^4)(x-2^5)=(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-3)(x-6)$$

Now, I can work out the computations and find $h(x)$,check polynomial, dividing $x^{12}-1$ by $g(x)$, but it seems a bit heavy to me. Is there any other possibility to compute the check polynomial faster?  And so also the parity check matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need to divide? You already know its structure as well as you know $g$'s:

It's equal to $(x-1)(x-5)(x-7)(x-9)(x-10)(x-11)(x-12)$

After you have this, you can use its corresponding word, then do cyclic shifts to find the rest of the parity matrix.

Comment: Yes sure, but in order to write the parity check I need the coefficients, and so to multiply everything. I was wondering if there was a faster way (?) @rschweib

Comment: Hrm, well I don't think you're going to get an explicit matrix without explicitly computing the polynomial for one of them.  One you have the parity polynomial, you can just use it as the first row then do cyclic shifts, right?

Comment: Multiplying 7 linear polynomials seems like slightly less work than multiplying 5 and dividing

Comment: I totally agree with you now:) Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to @rschweib's answer and possibly requiring little computation you have good look-up tables, a cyclic Reed-Solomon code whose generator polynomial has $2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5$ as roots has parity check matrix
$$H = \left[\begin{matrix}
1&2&2^2&2^3&\quad \cdots&2^{11}\\
1&2^2&(2^2)^2&(2^2)^3&\quad \cdots&(2^2)^{11}\\
1&2^3&(2^3)^2&(2^3)^3&\quad \cdots&(2^3)^{11}\\
1&2^4&(2^4)^2&(2^4)^3&\quad \cdots&(2^4)^{11}\\
1&2^5&(2^5)^2&(2^5)^3&\quad \cdots&(2^5)^{11}
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: I found in my book this statement, thanks! But, the matrix you proposed is the transposed one actually.

Comment: @bobinthebox "matrix you proposed is transposed"  Well, that is entirely a matter of notational choices. For some such as myself, $H$ is a $(n-k)\times n$ matrix, a codeword $C$ is a row vector ($1\times n$ matrix) and every codeword $C$ satisfies $HC^T=0$ where that $0$ is a $(n-k)\times 1$ matrix or column vector of zeroes. Others write $C\mathcal H=0$ where  $\mathcal H = H^T$ is the transpose of what I have called $H$ and that $0$ is a row vector of $(n-k)$ zeroes. To each his own.

Comment: Yes , I was exactly assuming the same notation as you, but looking at the book "http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/mashker/files/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B2.pdf", pg. 177, it seems the matrix is different, I think I should have the first row made by all $1$'s...

Comment: @DilipSarwate - isn't H the syndrome generation matrix as seen on page 180 of that  book: http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/mashker/files/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B2.pdf#page=199
 ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow up and for others reading this. I have old RS demo code that I used to generate the polynomials and matrices.

The 5 factor generator polynomial:

```
(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)(x-3)(x-6) = (x+11)(x+9)(x+5)(x+10)(x+7)
                          = x^5 + 3 x^4 + 5 x^3 + 12 x^2 + 11 x + 5
```

The remaining 7 factor polynomial. The coefficients of this polynomial correspond to the values in the bottom row of the parity generator matrix.

```
(x−1)(x−5)(x−7)(x−9)(x−10)(x−11)(x−12) = (x+12)(x+8)(x+6)(x+4)(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)
                          = x^7 + 3 x^6 + 4 x^5 + 9 x^4 + 6 x^3 + 6 x^2 + 2 x + 8
```

All 12 factors result in x^12 - 1:

```
(x-1)(x-2)...(x-11)(x-12) = (x+12)(x+11) ... (x+2)(x+1)
                          = x^12 + 12 = x^12 - 1
```

Parity generator matrix (in decimal despite the leading zeroes):

```
    05 02 07 06 04 04 10
    02 11 10 12 05 03 08
    12 12 07 01 06 12 01
    08 10 05 01 10 02 02
    03 04 09 06 06 02 08
```

Parity check matrix:

```
    05 02 07 06 04 04 10 01 00 00 00 00
    02 11 10 12 05 03 08 00 01 00 00 00
    12 12 07 01 06 12 01 00 00 01 00 00
    08 10 05 01 10 02 02 00 00 00 01 00
    03 04 09 06 06 02 08 00 00 00 00 01
```

Syndrome generator matrix:

```
    07 10 05 09 11 12 06 03 08 04 02 01
    10 09 12 03 04 01 10 09 12 03 04 01
    05 12 08 01 05 12 08 01 05 12 08 01
    09 03 01 09 03 01 09 03 01 09 03 01
    11 04 05 03 07 12 02 09 08 10 06 01
```

Comment: If the parity check poly is what you wrote, then I think that the parity check matrix is wrong... as the first row should  be differentt (and hence all the others)

Comment: it should be   (1,2,4,9,6,6,2,8) the first row

Comment: @bobinthebox - the message is multiplied by x^5 in order to append 5 zeroes to it, for room to store the parity bytes. The 5 parities (remainder) are calculated and subtracted from those 5 zeroes. Take a look at the last column of the parity generator matrix, {10, 8, 1, 2, 8}, after subtraction, it's {3, 5, 12, 11, 5}, the same as the coefficients to the 5 factor generator polynomial. The bottom row corresponds to the coefficients of the 7 factor polynomial.

Comment: @bobinthebox - that parity generator matrix was created from sets of elements where there is only a single 1:  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,0,0,0,0}, ... {0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, with known working RS code.  For example, a code word with a single 1 at the end of the message is the generator polynomial: {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,5,12,11,5}.

Comment: @bobinthebox - if interested, link to example code [eccb13.c](https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/eccb13.c). It's an interactive demo. Most of the options are obvious, except that 'P', is used to note locations of erasures. Use 'M' to generate matrices, 'X' to do parity check. It includes the 3 types of decoders, PGZ matrix, SugiYama's extended Euclid (hardware like since the original purpose was for hardware team, where I made a smaller version), Berlekamp Massey. It's based on 1990's code, which explains the usage of Hungarian notation.

Comment: many thanks for your time ;) @rcgldr